# JQgrid headers are not at the same line as columns

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am new here. I have that kind of problem:
[image]

I want:
- column width must depend of text lenght.
- headers must be at the same line as columns.

I have tried many solutions (like `shinkToFit:true;` `showColWidth` etc), but without no success.
I am using **jqgrid 4.4.**

And here is the function which resize my columns:

```
<script>
function resize(tagName){

var elements = document.getElementById('gbox_list').getElementsByTagName(tagName);

for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {

      elements[i].setAttribute("style", "display:inherit);
      }

   }
</script>
```

I here I am calling this function:

```
< button type="button" onclick="resize('tr');" >Przycisk< /button>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have any console error?

Comment: Most of the problems regarding this are the inconsistency of the colModel and data returned from the server. If possible provide a demo with data in order to see in the problem more detailed.

Comment: I don't have any console error.